# Laravel parse request into Eloquent model with relations

Tags: php, json, laravel, api, laravel-5

Im developing a Laravel API that will host and manage the data for a mobile application. The application that I am writing will make AJAX requests and send over JSON data to the Laravel controller.

This works fine for a basic model however I am unable to get this working for nested models. Ill explain:

So I have the following model structure:

**Shelf** ---- *Has Many* ----> **Boxes** ---- *Has Many* ----> **Products**

**Shelf:**

```
class Shelf extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'location'];

    public function boxes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Box');
    }
}
```

**Box:**

```
class Box extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'size', 'label'];

    public function shelf()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Shelf');
    }

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
    }
}
```

**Product:**

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'price', 'quantity'];

    public function box()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Box');
    }
}
```

All my models have validation checking before anything is saved.

I send the following request to my Laravel controller:

```
{
  "name":"Shelf 1",
  "location":"LOC1"
  "boxes":[{
    "name":"box 1",
    "size": 130,
    "label": "B1",
    "products":[
      {"name":"Prod1","price":23.00,"quantity":5},
      {"name":"Prod2","price":13.00,"quantity":2}
    ]
  }, {
    "name":"box 2",
    "size": 130,
    "label": "B2",
    "products":[
      {"name":"Prod3","price":3.00,"quantity":15},
      {"name":"Prod4","price":7.00,"quantity":8}
    ]
  }, {
    "name":"box 3",
    "size": 160,
    "label": "B3",
    "products":[
      {"name":"Prod5","price":103.00,"quantity":9},
      {"name":"Prod6","price":83.00,"quantity":1}
    ]
  }]
}
```

When I receive the above data in my Laravel controller i use:

```
$shelf = new Shelf;
$shelf->fill($request->all());
$shelf->save();
```

To get all of the data however this will only save the Shelf and not any of the relationships. Is there a common way (or library) I can use to parse the JSON within the Laravel controller?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware Eloquent doesn't offer anything like that. You would need to save each one individually. May I suggest something like this:

```
$shelf = Shelf::create($request->only(['name', 'location']));
foreach ( $request->input('boxes') as $box )
{
    $box = new Box($box);
    $shelf->boxes()->save($box);
    $pTemp = [];
    foreach ( $box['products'] as $product )
    {
        $pTemp[] = new Product($product);
    }
    $box->products()->saveMany($pTemp);
}
```

### Update

To minimise the number of queries run we can loop through all the boxes once, create them then loop through them again to create all the products. You're still having to run one query per box to create the products, but as far as I can see there is no way around that.

```
$shelf = Shelf::create($request->only(['name', 'location']));
$bTemp = [];
foreach ( $request->input('boxes') as $i => $box )
{
    $bTemp[$i] = new Box($box);
}
$shelf->boxes()->saveMany($bTemp);
foreach ( $request->input('boxes') as $i => $box )
{
    $pTemp = [];
    foreach ( $box['products'] as $product )
    {
        $pTemp[] = new Product($product);
    }
    $bTemp[$i]->products()->saveMany($pTemp);
}
```

Comment: That is great thank you for the code sample I will give it a try. My only concern is that it looks like it is saving the boxes individually within the loop and therefore making potentially a lot of database calls? Say I had 500 boxes to save within a shelf this would be doing 1 call for the shelf 500 calls for the boxes and another 500 calls for the products is there no way I can do one DB query to save all? Im just trying to make my code as efficient as possible.

Comment: Hi Glen, you can make multiple loops through, first for the boxes then for the products and create all the boxes in one go using `saveMany` as I have for products above. I'll add another example for you.

Comment: Thats great thank you for the updated answer. Lets say that there was a validation error when creating one of the boxes, if this happens and i return the errors within the loop when the validation fails the shelf will have already been created and stored in the DB. Is there anyway to roll back any data that has just been created?

Comment: Thats great ill ask the validation question in another question on here. Thanks